# Cannot retrieve last inserted id EF core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.2

While I understand there are many articles online about this I cannot seem to find solution to my problem. One reason is all articles I found aren't using async function. Here is my problem:

I have entity:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Url]
public string LogoUrl { get; set; }
[Required]
public string AdministratorIdentityId { get; set; }
public string Verified { get; set; }
public int AddressId { get; set; }
```

I have following in my db context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder model)
{
        model.Entity<RestaurantEntity>()
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever();

        base.OnModelCreating(model);
}
```

And my code to save information to database is this:

```
try
{
    RestaurantEntity dbrestaurant = new RestaurantEntity();
    dbrestaurant.Name = restaurantName;
    dbrestaurant.AdministratorIdentityId = restaurantAdministrator;
    dbrestaurant.Verified = GenerateVerifiedCode();

    await _appDbContext.Restaurants.AddAsync(dbrestaurant);
    await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    int newpk = dbrestaurant.Id;

    return newpk;
}
```

My problem is that newpk is ALWAYS 0, while in DB generates proper value. For some reason EF core is not retrieving inserted value.

This is code retrieving info:

[image]

This is DB value:

[image]

Comment: why you use "ValueGeneratedNever();" at "ModelCreating"?

Comment: At first I was reading online that my issue was because entity was getting value of 0, thus I should use that to make sure 0 is not generated, although still generates 0 for new entity ID, that is the reason why I have it.

Comment: Do you understand this `model.Entity<RestaurantEntity>()
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever();`?

Comment: With `.ValueGeneratedNever()` you tell "Hey mr. EntityFramework! I will handle this entity key generation by my self. Please, don't set it and don't read it from db right after you insert this entity." What do you expect?

Comment: i think the moral of this story is to read the documentation and just dont use peoples code and answers unless you understand them completely and have truly debugged and identified your problem

Comment: I don’t think any of you understood what I wrote, I read info online and I understood it as “hey before you send this to DB, do not create value of 0 for ID of this entity”.... This was because I had issue inserting data into DB. Moral of the story is that English is not my first language and it was just misunderstanding, if you cannot write nice answer, point to documentation and explain your answer do not be toxic and “above others” because it won’t get you far

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

to

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id {get;set;}
```